# Number of ways to compose a number such that there is a maximum pile size and for each pile size there are a finite number of valid piles of that size

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

So, I want to count all of the different ways that a number $n$ can be written as the sum of numbers that are less than or equal to $k$ where the order of the numbers matters. Now, this is just composition, which is not very hard to solve. However, in the problem I am working on, there are "duplicates" of the numbers. By this I mean, one of the ways of breaking $11$ down would be $1,3,3,4$ but also $1,3,3',4$ and $1,3',3,4$ etc. We assume the number of duplicates for a given $x$ is $f_x$. Now, the number of ways this can happen for a given partition is just the length of the partition divided by the product of the factorials of each number that a certain number and its equivalents appears, but I want to be able to manipulate this using summation and product notation (I'm fine with a summation over a partition or something) rather than having to use words or the $0$-indicator function or an Iverson Bracket or something. I've played around with it for a while, and I can get it in terms of those, but I don't know how to get it in a more nice and purely combinatorial way.

Also, sorry if this is really messily written, I'm not sure how to make myself more clear.

At the suggestion from @Karl I will give an example of what I mean here: Let's say we are looking at splitting up the number $4$ and there is $1$ way we can have the number $1$, $3$ ways of having the number $2$, $1$ way of having the number $3$, and $2$ ways of having the number $4$. The following is (hopefully) all of the valid ways:
1,1,1,1 | 2,1,1 | 1,2,1 | 1,1,2 | 2',1,1 | 1,2',1 | 1,1,2' | 2'',1,1 | 1,2'',1 | 1,1,2'' | 2,2 | 2,2' | 2,2'' | 2',2 | 2',2' | 2',2'' | 2'',2 | 2'',2' | 2'',2'' | 1,3 | 3,1 | 4 | 4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write your counting function as

$$c(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{x_1,\dots,x_n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}\\\sum_{i=1}^n ix_i=n}\binom{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{x_1,\dots,x_n}\prod_{i=1}^n w_i^{x_i}$$

where $w_i$ is the number of distinguishable versions of $i$ you have. The outer summation sums over [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ (keeping track of how many parts of each size there are), the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) counts the ways of ordering the partition, and the product counts the ways of choosing versions. The $w_i$ can be set to zero, making your $k$ parameter redundant.